# Upload an image without displaying file_field and "apply" button. What's the correct way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working in a rails 3.2 app,where the user has the avatar picture.

The user can chose his avatar in these way:
1) chose the file clicking the "Browse..." button in the edit user view (using file_field)
2) chose the file and click OK
3) then click on the "Apply Photo"  button (on the right of the field containing the filename) to load the image to the server and update the view

I want improve the user experience, removing the field and the button in the view. This should be the way:

1) click a link 'Update avatar' (or directly click on the picture)
2) chose the file and click OK

No (visible) fields and no Apply button

What's the best way to do that ? 
should I continue to use the file_field in the view but hide it and trigger the user#update action using some javascript code ? or is there some other better way to do that ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of js plugins to upload files. I.e. if you are using jQuery, you can try using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)

Comment: thanks Eru, I know that there are many plugins about uploading, but I don't need async upload or complicated thinks, just to hide the field and the apply button

Comment: You can hide the field, bind a click event to the button that will trigger a click event on the field. Next thing you need to do is to bind a change event on the field to submit the form with js.

Comment: +1! I've found a good explanation that more or less says what you said in your comment. The point is: hide the field using the opacity, so it's possible to interact with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173453/ruby-on-rails-file-field-how-do-i-remove-the-upload-button

Comment: the problem with the solution you linked is that if the filed is hidden with opacity property somewhere in the content area, when u mistakenly click on it it will throw you a browse window. Doing it with events prevents you from it. Then you can hide it or (even better for older browsers) leave it visible with position: absolute and left: -999em so it's always far away from the content.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue with hiding the input element and putting a label instead.

For eliminating submit button, I have added `onchange` method.

```
<%= file_field_tag :file, class: "d-none", onchange: "this.form.submit()" %>
<%= label_tag :file, role: "button" do %>
  <%= image_pack_tag('logo.svg') %>
<% end %>
```

PS: I'm using bootstrap class here, styles can be used instead for hiding the element.

Answer (score 0):

The button near upload field is generated by browser and is standart widget for browser. You can use js plugin for that or realize iframe upload method (allow you async file upload even on IE). Simple tutorial for iframe - [there](http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-easiest-asynchronous-upload-file-ajax-upload/) Iframe method allow to you to customize upload link/field as you want =)